# Create a buffer (terra::buffer) and keep original vector object attributes

Tags: r, geospatial, terra

I would like to use Terra::buffer to create a buffer of x meters around a series of points and keep the original vector objects' (e.g., points) attributes.

Alternatively, once I have my buffer with no attributes, how do I merge these dataset. Something like merge by location in a traditional GIS.

Comment: Used terra::intersect seems to provide the columns and rows but the dataset are empty. I can force the data into that empty dataset but I need to be sure those cells are connected with the appropiate geometry.

Comment: Read [MCVE] and [ask].

Comment: That is what `terra::buffer` does. So what is your question? Also, you should not comment on your own question. You can edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Create some example point data with attributes

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- vect(f)
set.seed(1)
p <- spatSample(v, 5)
p
# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : points 
# dimensions  : 5, 6  (geometries, attributes)
# extent      : 5.962628, 6.351843, 49.59884, 49.86376  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
# names       :  ID_1       NAME_1  ID_2     NAME_2  AREA   POP
# type        : <num>        <chr> <num>      <chr> <num> <int>
# values      :     1     Diekirch     3    Redange   259 18664
#                   3   Luxembourg    11     Mersch   233 32112
#                   2 Grevenmacher     6 Echternach   188 18899
```

1000 meter buffer

```
b <- buffer(p, 1000)
b
# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : polygons 
# dimensions  : 5, 6  (geometries, attributes)
# extent      : 5.94872, 6.365734, 49.58985, 49.87275  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
# names       :  ID_1       NAME_1  ID_2     NAME_2  AREA   POP
# type        : <num>        <chr> <num>      <chr> <num> <int>
# values      :     1     Diekirch     3    Redange   259 18664
#                   3   Luxembourg    11     Mersch   233 32112
#                   2 Grevenmacher     6 Echternach   188 18899
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked as I would have expected. Not sure what was causing my original issue.